# Is there a YUI equivalent to JQuerys ajaxCompleted()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yui

Ideally I'd like to attach a listener to a DOM element, listening for when an ajax request on that element has completed, or some method that will get the same effect.

This is on a page where I can't edit the existing YUI code.

Answer (score 0):

basic example of ajax call with callback

```
    function YUI(){
        var loadUrl = "Loading.html";
        var callback = {
            success: function(o) {
                document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML =  o.responseText;
            },
            failure: function(o) {
                alert("AJAX doesn't work"); //FAILURE
            }
        }

        var transaction = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', loadUrl, callback, null);
        return false;
    }
```